# Compare two Folder Contents using c#

Tags: c#

I need to compare two folder contents based on

```
1.No of files
2.Size of files
3 date
```

and i got an error index out of bound exception in this piece of code

```
 private void SeekFiles(string Root)
    {
    string[] Files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Root);
    string[] Folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Root);
    FileInfo File;
       for(int i=0; i< Folders.Length; i++)
    {
    File = new FileInfo(Files[i]);
    FolderSize += File.Length;
    }

    for(int i=0; i< Folders.Length-1; i++)
    {
    SeekFiles(Folders[i]);
    }
    }
```

Any Suggestion??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using wrong index on a wrong collection :

```
for(int i=0; i< Folders.Length; i++)
{
    File = new FileInfo(Files[i]);
    FolderSize += File.Length;
}
```

Should be :

```
for(int i=0; i< **Files.Length**; i++)
{
    File = new FileInfo(Files[i]);
    FolderSize += File.Length;
}
```

Comment: I used `**Files.Length**` to highlight the place where error was. Just remove **s and use `Files.Length` instead.

Comment: just remove the ** from the for loop :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using Files[i] but i < Folders.Length in the first for.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i< Folders.Length; i++)

{
File = new FileInfo(Files[i]);
FolderSize += File.Length;
}
```

This should be `Files.Length`